# Roblox Studio keeps saying "You need to sign in to publish your project"

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I'm having a problem publishing my Roblox Studio Project, I'm signed in but the program keeps saying:

> You need to sign in to publish your project

I'm on Roblox Studio latest version and Windows 10 32-bit (Not Anniversary Update)

If something's wrong about Roblox Studio, please reply!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try signing in. Go into the view tab, then press Start Page. From there you should be able to log in, and once again publish your place.

If you are already signed in, then perhaps you're not using the account that the place is on.

Comment: I am very sorry MagisterTech, your solution didn't work. But I hope someone finds a solution for it!

Comment: Oh, I apologize that it didn't work. Have you tried emailing ROBLOX? Their email is: info@roblox.com . Hopefully they'll have a solution to your problem. I'm afraid not many robloxians roam this realm.

Answer (score 0):

You could back up all your data and re-install Roblox Studio. This is not a problem on Roblox's side and it may be a corrupt file (I really don't know).